# Storing SHA1 hex value in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, hex, sha1

Seemingly simple question, corresponds to another question that was asked with regards to MySQL: How does one store the hex value that results from a SHA1 hash in a PostgreSQL database?

Note: I realize I could use a VARCHAR(40) field, but this isn't efficient, as the data is in hex. Also, I am using PHP to interact with the database, so I can use PHP functions if necessary, but if this is the case, what do I store the result as in the database?

Comment: "but this isn't efficient, as the data is in hex" --- uhm, what? HEX is just a human readable data representation, nothing else. If you see something looks like a hex-string it only means that it's formatted so

Comment: If you're working with PHP, isn't the SHA1 hash already in hex? Why are you hex-encoding it in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store as bytea, hex encoded.  Converting the human-readable hex data to bytea is simply a matter of:

```
  ('\x' || sha1_hex_value)::bytea
```

The only real disadvantage here is that depending on your app framework you may get a binary representation out.  If not you will get an escaped version  and depending on the escape settings, may want to convert to binary yourself (if it is hex though you can just strip off the `\x` at the front of the value and use as hex).

Comment: `bytea` is certainly the most storage-efficient option. If your app framework can't cope with getting binary back when it expects text it's possible it'll behave better if you *send* binary as well as receive. Just decode the hex into the real bytes of the md5 and send those to Pg as a `bytea` using your language's parameterized query facilities.